# Despite Adding Error Tags, Form Not Submitted and No Error Printed in Template

Tags: python, django

I want to preview all data submitted by a user before saving the form in the database. I wrote the below code, but it's not submitting and it's not showing me an error. Even when I insert print to the code so as to print data inputted, it didn't print any data.

So the logic is this, when a user add the data and click confirm order, he/she will be taken to 'preview.html' where the data submitted will be displayed. And when the user is satisfied, he/she will click on save button. The form action in the preview.html is /add_buy_order/'.

VIEWS

```
@login_required
def add_buy_order(request):
    newbc = None
    template_name = 'ctrade/buycurrency.html'
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=BuyCurForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.cleaned_data
            requested_amount_needed = request.POST.get('amount_needed')
            deck_am_needed = Decimal(requested_amount_needed) 
            fixed_amount = Decimal('999.0')
            requested_amount_to_pay = request.POST.get('amount_to_pay')
            requested_disc_code = request.POST.get('discount_code')
            requested_disc_value = request.POST.get('discount_value')
            requested_cur_one = request.POST.get('cur_address')
            requested_cur_two = request.POST.get('cur_address_two')
            requested_bank = request.POST.get('deaccount')
            tapde = DEAccount.objects.get(bank_name= requested_bank)


            if not str(requested_cur_one) == str(requested_cur_two):
                messages.info(request, 'Address to fund mismatch. Cross-check again')
                return redirect('add_buy_order')

            if '_preview' in request.POST:
                newbc=BuyCur(
                    buyer=request.user,
                    cur_type = data['cur_type'],
                    amount_needed = data['amount_needed'],
                    deaccount = tapde, 
                    amount_to_pay = data['amount_to_pay'],
                    cur_address = data['cur_address'],
                    cur_address_two = data['cur_address_two'],
                    rate_bought = data['rate_bought'],
                    cur_note = data['cur_note'],
                    pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                    modified_date = datetime.datetime.now(),
                    discount_code = data['discount_code']
                )
                print newbc.buyer, newbc.cur_type, newbc.amount_needed, newbc.deaccount, newbc.amount_to_pay, newbc.cur_address,
                newbc.cur_address_two, newbc.rate_bought, newbc.cur_note, newbc.pub_date, newbc.modified_date, newbc.discount_code

                return render(request, 'ctrade/preview.html',{'newbc':newbc})

            elif '_save' in request.POST:
                newbc=BuyCur(
                    buyer=request.user,
                    cur_type = data['cur_type'],
                    amount_needed = data['amount_needed'],
                    deaccount = tapde, 
                    amount_to_pay = data['amount_to_pay'],
                    cur_address = data['cur_address'],
                    cur_address_two = requested_cur_two,
                    rate_bought = data['rate_bought'],
                    cur_note = data['cur_note'],
                    pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                    modified_date = datetime.datetime.now(),
                    discount_code = data['discount_code'])
                newbc.save()
                return render(request, 'ctrade/afterbuy.html', {'newbc':newbc})
    else:
        form=BuyCurForm()
    return render(request, template_name,{'form':form,'newbc':newbc})
```

FORM

```
class BuyCurForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cur_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = CurrencyTrade.objects.all(), to_field_name = "we_sell")
    deaccount = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = DEAccount.objects.all(), to_field_name = "bank_name")
    amount_needed = forms.DecimalField(widget= forms.TextInput, max_digits=10,  decimal_places=1, initial=0.0 ,required = True)
    amount_to_pay = forms.DecimalField(widget= forms.TextInput, max_digits=10,  decimal_places=2, initial=0.00 ,required = True)
    rate_bought = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuyCurForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['amount_to_pay'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['rate_bought'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = BuyCur
        fields = ['cur_type','amount_needed','amount_to_pay','rate_bought','deaccount','cur_address','cur_address_two','cur_note','discount_code']
```

Template

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
     {% csrf_token %} 
      {% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit"   name="_preview"  value="Confirm Order">
<input type="hidden"  name="next" value="{{ next }}">
</form>
```

What am I missing? or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I've done that. @Alasdair

Comment: Are you certain the form is valid? You aren't displaying `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` in the template. You might also want to print `form.is_valid()` and `form.errors` in the view to help debugging.

Comment: As an aside, note that setting `widget.attrs['readonly']` will not prevent users from editing the value using their browser tools.

Comment: yeah form is valid because When I insert two wrong addresses in the cur_address and cur_address_two, I got an error saying address mismatch. But when all input are correct. It won't redirect me to the preview page. just return me back to the form with the data inputted. The issue here is, is '_preview' in request.POST working? I guess Django is not getting that part. @Alasdair

Comment: "I got an error saying address mismatch" - that means you've tested that the view works for invalid forms. It doesn't mean that your current form is valid. As I said, I would add `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` to the template, and print `form.is_valid()` and `form.errors` in the view to help debug the problem. If you want to debug the `_preview` part, then I would try printing `request.POST` in the view to see whether `preview` is there. Your current input `<input type="submit"  name="_preview"  value="Confirm Order">` looks OK to me (as long as that's the button you are clicking).

Comment: I did print form.is_valid() and it returns True. Don't know why it's not moving to the preview page and returning me back to the same page.

Comment: OK, next add some more printing to figure out the where the problem is. What does the view do inside the `if form.is_valid():`? Is that what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to do this.

1) If you want django messages,  then your template should contain below codes

template.html

```
   {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
       </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

2) If you want to use `form.errors` you should not send a new instance of form like you are doing currently. You should be sending the invalid form instance.

views.py

```
#######
else:
        form=BuyCurForm()
    return render(request, template_name,{'form':form,'newbc':newbc, })
```

correct views.py

```
####
else:
    return render(request, template_name,{'form':form,'newbc':newbc})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The major problem is the form not submitting. When I insert two wrong addresses in the cur_address and cur_address_two, I got an error saying address mismatch. But when all input are correct. It won't redirect me to the preview page. just return me back to the form with the data inputted. The issue here is, is  '_preview'  in request.POST working? I guess Django is not getting that part.